# 正体不明の重複メッセージ

Tags: ruby-on-rails

下記エラー: `` undefined method `errors' for nil:NilClass `` 。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]  

　スペルミス無し。

　暗中模索の結果、article_controller.rb の def new に @article = Article.new 追記でエラーは出なくなった。

　→ ▶︎今度は validation のメッセージが重複して出現。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

　▶︎models/article.rb

```
class Article < ApplicationRecord
    validates :title, presence: true, length: {minimum: 5}
end
```

▶︎articles_controller.rb

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @articles = Article.all
    end
    def show
        @article = Article.find params[:id]
    end
    def new
        @article = Article.new
    end
    def create
        @article = Article.new(article_params)
            if @article.save
                redirect_to article_path(@article)
            else
                render 'new'
    end
    end
    def article_params
        params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text)
    end
end
```

▶︎views/articles/new.html.erb

```
新規記事作成
<%= form_for :article, url: articles_path do |f| %>
    <% if @article.errors.any? %>
        <%= @article.errors.count %>個のエラーあり
            <%= @article.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
                <%= msg %>
            <% end %>
    <% end %>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
    <%= f.text_area :text %>
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

["Title can't be blank", "Title is too short (minimum is 5 characters)"]内の記述（不要）がどこからきているのか、検証の見方、回避する方法、をどなたかご教示いただけますと幸いです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

イコールを削除して `<% @article.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>` としてください。(イコールを付けると、評価した値をその場所に展開します。)

※はじめのうちは scaffold で雛形を作るのがオススメです。